# multiple problems--windows 7 mbr, others

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, mbr

After buying a new laptop(XPS L501X) with windows 7 preinstalled, I decided to make it dual boot with windows Vista. I now know about the issue with installing previous versions of windows, and the deletion of the MBR. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but Microsoft no longer sends install disks with their computers, so there is no way to just re-install windows 7. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. Data preservation is not an issue, as the laptop is new.

Comment: @andrew-do you have recovery disc's/repair disc/any system working?

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not Microsoft who no longer sends install disks, it is Dell who stopped it to save the measly cost of printing a DVD.
I would simply create another partition from Disk Manager in 7, then reboot from Vista installer and put it there, later, running [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) on Vista to restore the 7 boot option